# Same template class with type/non-type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, c++14

Given a template class `myclass`, is there a tricky way to allow this for the user :

```
myclass<void> x;
myclass<double> y;
myclass<42> z; // I do not expect the classic hack 
               // myclass<std::integral_constant<int, 42>>
```

because in certain context, it can make sense. My goal would be to allow this from the user point of view, regardless of the (possibly) awful metaprogramming hacks to allow it.

Note : if it is possible, I would like a solution without `boost` (only the standard library) to understand correctly all the details of the method.

Comment: You can do this [with function templates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1bb0643bfdf95de) but I doubt it's possible with class templates.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, from the C++ point of view. A template parameter is either a type or a value, not both. How would you exactly use this template parameter inside `myclass`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class template parameter is either a type or a value, so i can't think of a trick to handle both when instantiating classes directly. Functions are a different story, so let's introduce a make function:

```
template <typename T> struct myclass {};

template <int V> struct value {}; // helper

template <typename T> myclass<T>        make_myclass() { return myclass<T>(); }
template <int V>      myclass<value<V>> make_myclass() { return myclass<value<V>>(); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto a = make_myclass<void>();
    auto b = make_myclass<double>();
    auto c = make_myclass<42>();
}
```

Close enough?

Comment: You don't need `value<V>` plain `int` will do (e.g., `myclass<int>`). `value` class is useless. Although, not excactly what the OP wants. +1 for the idea.

Comment: @40two woops, misread.

Comment: @40two: I assume that the OP wants different myclass instantiations for different values.